# Jenkins returned status code 128 with github

Tags: github, jenkins

With GitHub command I have:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi (MyName)! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

My connection with GitHub is ok (no problem), but with Jenkins I have this error:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:Name-MysRepo/MyRepo.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git@github.com:Name-MysRepo/MyRepo.git
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clone(CliGitAPIImpl.java:219)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1001)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1101)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1369)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:241)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clone --progress -o origin git@github.com:Name-MysRepo/MyRepo.git /root/.jenkins/jobs/TestKRGDAOV01/workspace" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into '/root/.jenkins/jobs/TestKRGDAOV01/workspace'...

stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is this problem with public key?

I use `Jenkins` under `Tomcat 7` / `Ubuntu 12`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This error:

`stderr: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

indicates that Jenkins is trying to connect to github with the wrong ssh key.

You should:

1. Determine the user that jenkins runs as, eg. 'build' or 'jenkins'
2. Login on the jenkins host that is trying to do the clone - that is, do not login to the master if a node is actually doing the build.
3. Try you ssh to github - if it fails, then you need to add the proper key to `<jenkins user home>/.ssh`

Comment: I don't have access to the login to the master, but I created a new Jenkins job and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 18):

To check are the following:

1. if the right public key (id_rsa.pub) is uploaded to the git-server.
2. if the right private key (id_rsa) is copied to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/
3. if the known_hosts file is created inside ~/.ssh folder. Try `ssh -vvv git@github.com` to see debug logs. If thing goes well, github.com will be added to known_hosts.
4. if the permission of id_rsa is set to 700 (`chmod 700 id_rsa`)

After all checks, try `ssh -vvv git@github.com`.

Comment: Item 3 of this answer specifically solved my issue. One suggestion that I would like to add is to to make sure to su to jenkins so that item 3 will alter/create the correct known_hosts file for the jenkins account. I did that by running **sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins** as per information provide in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18081006/291612

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522862/repostiory-not-found-in-git-jenkins?noredirect=1#comment76037665_44522862 i am getting different error.. and jenkins folder doesn't exist inside var/lib folder..  can anybody help out

Answer (score 10):

Also make sure you using the ssh github url and not the https

Comment: Can you please expand upon this? Why does https work fine while running the job, but timesout during polling?

Comment: @Novaterata there are two protocols that Git can work with when communicating between server and client machines: HTTPS and SSH. Both use different formats for URLs and credentials for authentication.

Comment: @starscream_disco_party I understand that, what does that have to do with why http times out while polling

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to add the public key to my repo (at Bitbucket) AND use git clone once via ssh to answer yes to the "known host" question the first time.

Answer (score 3):

i had sometime ago the same issue.
make sure that your ssh key doesn't have password and use not common user account (e.g. better to user account called jenkins or so).

check following article http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2011/09/20/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

Answer (score 1):

When I got a similar `status code 128` error from Jenkins:

```
status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/jenkins

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1864)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:545)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:358)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:197)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:299)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It was because I hadn't pushed my new branch `"jenkins"` that had my `Jenkinsfile`. So the solution was to just push my changes

Comment: I think this is a valid answer, it's not your fault the OP choses a bad question title.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my project (root folder) and created it again. It was the fastest and simplest way in my case.

Do not forget to save all you changes, before you delete you project!

Answer (score 0):

I first had another credential, then when i deleted that, and created a new one, i had the same error. I had to go to every project, and select the new Credential.

Answer (score 0):

I am working under a firewall, for me the issue was just intermittent and got fixed on its own. Just retrying after a while fixed it for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34205947)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I'd moved the entire C:\ProgramData\Jenkins directory across from one PC to another. The workspace directory no longer corresponded properly, so I had to delete the .jenkins\workspace directory and give it a blank one to use - then it worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

I changed the permission of my .ssh/id_rsa (private key) to 604.
chmod 700 id_rsa