# Can't su to user jenkins after installing Jenkins

Tags: linux, unix, jenkins

I've installed jenkins and I'm trying to get into a shell as Jenkins to add an ssh key. I can't seem to su into the jenkins user:

```
[root@pacmandev /]# sudo su jenkins
[root@pacmandev /]# whoami
root
[root@pacmandev /]# echo $USER
root
[root@pacmandev /]#
```

The jenkins user exists in my /etc/passwd file. Runnin `su jenkins` asks for a password, but rejects my normal password. `sudo su jenkins` doesn't seem to do anything; same for `sudo su - jenkins`. I'm on CentOS.

Comment: user exists... but likely has no shell, see http://superuser.com/questions/566041/cannot-switch-to-jenkins-user-redhat-linux/566042#566042

Comment: You needn't sudo when you're root.  Though it doesn't hurt.

Comment: `sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Comment: don't add a shell to jenkins - it's missing one by design.  Generally you don't want service accounts to be able to log in interactively.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

jenkins is a service account, it doesn't have a shell by design.  It is generally accepted that service accounts shouldn't be able to log in interactively.

I didn't answer this one initially as it's a [duplicate of a question that has been moved to server fault](https://superuser.com/questions/566041/cannot-switch-to-jenkins-user-redhat-linux/566042#566042). I should have answered rather than linked to the answer in a comment.

if for some reason you want to login as jenkins, you can do so with:
`sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Comment: Thanks! I understand adding a shell to jenkins seems like a bad idea; I was just doing it because there were commands in my build process that I had no problem running from my shell but the build was failing because it couldn't run them. I wanted to get in as jenkins and see if there were permissions issues.

Comment: edited the answer to incorporate @mrg 's exactly correct info about needing `sudo`.

Comment: is there a default password that it asks for because I don't remember setting up a password on installation.

Comment: @mrg What password did you use?

Comment: @JoeLloyd Did you figure out the default password? What is the password?

Comment: There is no password - by design you cannot interactively log in to the account with a password.

Answer (score 6):

Use the below command:

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Answer (score 1):

When we installed a Jenkins its created a Jenkins user with = "/bin/false"

You will that information from cat /etc/password file.

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep jenkins
jenkins:x:995:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

the best way is already mentioned above in answer by @thekbb

```
su - jenkins -s /bin/bash
```

we can also switch with any other shell mentioned in /etc/shells file.

```
cat /etc/shells
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh
```

to make the changes permanently you can modify the  /etc/passwd, but it's highly not recommended because its a service/application user like Apache,MySQL,Nginx.

```
jenkins:x:995:993:Jenkins Automation Server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

If you using jenkins inside docker. Then you should try the following.

- First you need to run the jenkins container
    **"docker start (container-name or container-id)"**
- Then run this command **"docker exec -it (container-name or container-id) bash"**

Now hopefully you will be using as a jenkins user.

Answer (score -2):

Below mentioned command worked for me

"sudo su jenkins"

Answer (score -11):

as root, enter *su - jenkins*

Also, check in */etc/passwd* that user jenkins is allowed to logon: there should be something like */bin/bash* or */bin/sh*, certainly not */bin/false* at the end of the line.

Hint: You don't use *su* and *sudo* at the same time.

Comment: that's exactly the command the OP tried... you're correct as to why jenkins can't log in - but I disagree with your solution.