# Is Jenkins capable to execute remote command?

Tags: jenkins

can you please guide me on what is wrong with the job? I created a "pogi" user on jenkins box and it is able to do passwordless ssh this command to appbox:

[pogi@jenkinsbox .ssh]# ssh pogi@appbox '/home/pogi/test-script.sh'
Last login: Thu Sep  3 18:04:12 2015 from 10.40.167.215

But applying it on Jenkins I got this error:

```
Started by user pogi
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test remote commad/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6957625423493115568.sh
+ ssh pogi@jenkinsbox /home/paops/test.sh
Host key verification failed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is shown in your console output: `Host key verification failed.`

The user that Jenkins runs as has never logged into that server before, so needs to verify the host key.  This can't be done from a non-interactive session, so it fails.

You can solve this by logging into the Jenkins server as the jenkins user, then running `ssh appbox` (or `ssh jenkinsbox` — your question text and the console output seem to contradict one another) and accepting the host key.  Then the next Jenkins build will succeed.

Or you can use something like the [SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) which should automate this for you.

Comment: I was actually trying to sudo su - jenkins on jenkins box but it always landed to root user? forgive me sir I'm still zero on jenkins. Is there a default password for jenkins user after installed?

Comment: `sudo su - jenkins` is correct. There is probably no password set on the Jenkins account; but since you have root access, you should be able to set one, if required.

Answer (score 0):

The jenkins account is a service account, and generally you can't su to a service account.

Read this for more info : [Can't su to user jenkins after installing Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068358/cant-su-to-user-jenkins-after-installing-jenkins)

If you still want to try, you can try:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```