# Make Jenkins run docker without sudo

Tags: jenkins, docker

I would like to run `Docker` shell commands on `Jenkins` like:

`docker ps`

Is it possible to do it with out using any plugins? Since Jenkins isn't a `user`, but [a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081006/3014866) how can I add to `docker group`?

Comment: Just as an FYI from a security point of view: giving someone permissions to run docker is similar to giving them sudo or root access. Don't be fooled into thinking that someone who can run docker is a restricted user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First execute

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Then execute

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then logout **its important to logout because your group membership is re-evaluated**

Login and try again

```
docker ps
```

It works!

Comment: This is in fact the solution

Comment: Worked for me. CentOS 7

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to restart Docker with `sudo service docker restart`.

Answer (score 5):

Following approach worked for me to run docker commands without any plugins

Rather than adding jenkins user to docker group, allowed jenkins user to run sudo commands with out prompting for password and then created an alias to avoid sudo in Dockerfile for jenkins slave.  I had to install docker client in the container which connects to daemon running in the host machine.

```
 ## allowing jenkins user to run sudo commands
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
 ## avoid typing sudo in command line
RUN echo "alias docker='sudo docker '" >> /home/jenkins/.bashrc
```

Comment: If I am not missing something, this is a really good solution when facing [the problem that, when running Jenkins inside a Docker container, the `docker` group inside the container has a different ID than the one on the host](http://vitorbaptista.com/how-to-access-hosts-docker-socket-without-root). This way, it can be solved at build time without having to hook in as root user before the base image's entrypoint script, then switch user again and run the actual entrypoint script.

Comment: wouldn't `RUN echo "jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: docker" >> /etc/sudoers` give rights only to sudo docker, and so better simulate a docker group ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the jenkins user I get from the official jenkins/jenkins docker image (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) doesn't seem to load .bashrc before executing the jenkins.sh, so I still get `/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied` errors. If I log to the container with `docker exec bash` I have access to docker without problems. So I've tried to change the Entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "bash", "-i", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]` but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Jenkins user has no home. If you want to do that define a global alias `echo "alias docker='sudo docker '" >> /etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh`

Answer (score 4):

(Taken from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/477554)

If you run on Ubuntu and Jenkins runs directly on the host machine (i.e. not inside a Docker container):

Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Add the user "jenkins" to the docker group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker
```

Restart the Docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Either do a `newgrp docker` or log out/in to activate the changes to groups.

Comment: seems that `jenkins` is not a user, but service account

Comment: If you are going to advocate for this approach, you should also mention the security implications.

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue when I was running from jenkins pipeline. I added jenkins user to docker group, restarted the docker engine and rebooted the machine as well. However I still get the same error `dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`.

Finally I added jenkins to root group and it resolved my issue (ubuntu 18.04) (VM on Azure)

```
sudo gpasswd -a jenkins root
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this did.