# How can i establish connection between docker daemon on my machine and Jenkins to execute docker commands?

Tags: java, spring, rest, docker, jenkins

My Jenkins file:

```
     pipeline {
       agent any

   stages {

     stage('Initialize') {
       steps {
         script {
           def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
           env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
         }
       }
     }


     stage('Build') {
       steps {
         echo 'building backend...'
         withGradle() {
             sh './gradlew build'
         }
       }
     }

     stage('Test') {
       steps {
         echo 'testing'
       }
     }

     stage('Deploy') {
       steps {
         echo 'deploying'
         sh './gradlew jibBuildTar'
         sh 'docker load --input build/image.tar'

       }
     }

   }
 }
```

Jenkins does not let me use docker command because docker daemon is not running. How can i connect my daemon to jenkins? 
i Have docker and docker pipeline plugins installed on jenkins too.

Comment: Install docker on some executor and run steps/stages that require docker on this specific executor.

Comment: what do you mean by executor? could you give me  example?

Comment: [First googled article](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-03-configure-master-and-slave) shows how to register and configure slave node on jenkins and how to use `node()` keyword in pipeline.

Comment: so if i add node() keyword instead of agent it will start working on my host master machine ?  thanks i will try it : )   P.S i think i need to add node anyway because master node won't work right?

Comment: You can make it work on master the same as on slave workers. If you don't mind executing everything on one machine. Depending on your infrastructure you should choose the best solution for you. If you want to make it work on master just connect to your master and configure properly docker on it.

Comment: Thanks. i will try it later :)

Comment: Hey i tried node method node('master') but it still gives me an error :Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Sure if you don't fix docker on your master machine then it will never work.

Comment: systemctl status docker shows active on master machine. do i need anything else?

Comment: Can you execute with success docker commands when you connect manually?

Comment: Yes it loads successfully .

Comment: Did you [add jenkins user to docker group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150370/10950272)?

Comment: I have this stage : 
 stage('Initialize') {
    script {
      def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
      env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }
  }
could this be cause of an issue ?

Comment: I don't have jenkins installed on host machine

Comment: I'm confused. `master` is the place you want to execute your pipeline. So this is the place which you should be investigating if docker is istalled properly and user which executes jenkins commands on in should have access to docker commands (should be added to docker group).

Comment: hey it seems like docker was not installed on master machine. it is not my machine so i confused it with different one. It works fine now since i contacted owner of master node . thanks for support :)

Comment: I posted answer with summary of our discussion, if it helped then you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum up of discussion:

By default Jenkins executes on `master` node. Docker must be installed on `master` node and Jenkins user needs to be allowed to execute docker commands ([should be added to docker group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638772/make-jenkins-run-docker-without-sudo/41150370#41150370)).