# Jenkins User Login - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I tried to login to jenkins user to add a ssh key. but i could not login using.

```
 su jenkins
```

It prompts me for a password.It fails when i try with passwords.
I tried few times and no clues yet.
Is there any quicker way login to jenkins user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah Found the solution
running

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

did the job.
similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068358/cant-su-to-user-jenkins-after-installing-jenkins) too