# Jenkins - Can't push tag to remote repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have just installed Jenkins on windows 7 and tried to create a test build for github repositories.

I tried to create a very simple build and it was successful. Now I wanted to try "Git Publisher" post build action. I thought of pushing a simple tag after successful build.

Here is the screen-shot of the build job:

[image]

[image]

But when I am building the job it consistently gives below error on console. I can guess that issue is related to credentials and account setup but I don't know to proceed. Please point me to some references which can help me out.

[image]

Here is the screen-shot of manage credentials. The only problem is once I save and re-open "Manage Credentials" ssh private key disappears.

[image]

**[EDIT-1] After the ssh key setup, I am getting below error message now:**

```
>     21:58:24  Pushing tag tag02 to repo gitrepo
>     21:58:24  ERROR: Failed to push tag tag02 to gitrepo
>     21:58:24  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: /usr/bin/git push
> git@github.paypal.com:atagrawal/maven-test-3.git tag02
>     21:58:24  Command "/usr/bin/git push git@github.paypal.com:atagrawal/maven-test-3.git tag02" returned
> status code 128: ERROR: Permission to atagrawal/maven-test-3.git
> denied to gitadmin.
>     21:58:24  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>     21:58:24  
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:776)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:741)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.push(GitAPI.java:788)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher$3.invoke(GitPublisher.java:277)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher$3.invoke(GitPublisher.java:247)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2154)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
>     21:58:24      at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     21:58:24      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     21:58:24      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     21:58:24      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     21:58:24      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     21:58:24      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>     21:58:24  Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git push git@github.paypal.com:atagrawal/maven-test-3.git
> tag02" returned status code 128: ERROR: Permission to
> atagrawal/maven-test-3.git denied to gitadmin.
>     21:58:24  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>     21:58:24  
>     21:58:24      at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:771)
>     21:58:24      ... 14 more
>     21:58:24  Build step 'Git Publisher' changed build result to FAILURE
>     21:58:24  Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
>     21:58:24  ### mvnpublisher.perform:class hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet
```

Comment: The error is "authentication failed". Have you setup the SSH key associated with your github user account?

Comment: I tried doing it using "Manage Credentials" but not sure if its the right way. Pls check the updated Screen-shot and description.

Comment: You have not setup a key to use in authenticating with Github. That's your problem. I suggest reading the github documentation. Start here: https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Comment: As per your suggestion, I was following the guide to do setup for SSH agent forwarding. I have completed step 1 but I am not sure about the 2nd step "Set your deploy script to use agent forwarding if it has a setting".

Comment: Ignore that part. Read the section on deploy keys and I highly suggest reading about how SSH works generally. Lots of good guides on the internet. Once you've established a successful connection to Github you'll be in a better position to understand how to setup Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark.After the ssh key setup, I tried again on jenkins and now I am getting different error - please see edit for error message.

Comment: That is a new question, duplicated by this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721629/jenkins-returned-status-code-128-with-github