# Repository not found in git jenkins

Tags: git, macos, jenkins

[image]

I am using the jenkins 2.64 with installed latest plugins.

I am trying to set the git repo in jenkins and given credentials, but giving the error failed to connect repository with status code 128.

```
Cloning repository https://github.com/somerepository.git
 > git init /Users/kumar/.jenkins/workspace/sample # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/somerepository.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/somerepository.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/somerepository.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/somerepository.git/' not found

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:545)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1067)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1107)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anybody helpout?

Note : for previous versions of jenkins has git section in manage jenkins-> configure where we can place our git executable. but didn't find git section in new version of jenkins.

edit: added log

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721629/jenkins-returned-status-code-128-with-github

Comment: Are you pretty sure that you have rights with that user on git repo? If 'yes' try call 'git ls-remote -h https: // github....' from command prompt also on your local machine. My problem was that even if I was trying to access git with an account that has rights, Jenkins was trying to connect with another account that hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

> Fetching upstream changes from `https://github.com/somerepository.git`
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress
>   `https://github.com/somerepository.git`
>   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: remote: Repository not found.

*Usually https git URL will not have .git at the end*. Please confirm your URL. 
I guess you are trying to access an ssh url.

Comment: yes.. what you said is right https git URL will not have .git. I tried initially without .git, but result was same. no i am not trying any ssh url.. i was able to clone the https url in git command line.

Comment: Then it's n/w problem. You might have to talk to your n/w team whether the IP of repository domain is blocking or not. If you want to confirm - add a simple shell script (bash script) in jenkins and execute the same command (git clone) which you did in your machine's command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to make your Jenkins as ssh keyless. Its failure as its unable to fetch your password to enter git. 
Its failing to pull the repo.

for  ssh-keygen on jenkins after you login as su - jenkins

copy the key ssh-rsa.pub and paste it in enterprise github setting

there is an option for ssh key add

paste this publish key.

Give the  git repository url and in credentials click none and specify your git branch to be pulled in branch section.

Answer (score -2):

This just means your user ID isn't valid. Maybe it's suspended, maybe it's no longer active. Go back to the Jenkins job page and click Configure. Select a valid ID and save the changes. You should be using a service account anyway, not a personal account.

If you have to use the account that's already there, go to your ops/admin folks and get the ID reinstated.