# Git fetch command randomly fails with error code 128

Tags: git, azure, jenkins

We use a Gerrit-triggered Jenkins pipeline to build an HTML app and everything works fine except the Azure deployment stage, which fails from time to time. At the beginning of the project, it would fail once in a while, but recently (as the project grows I suspect), it reached the point where only 1 deployment out of 10 would succeed.

The pipeline runs on one of 3 Linux VM and could succeed or fail on any of them.

The issue is always the same:

> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress
>   https://.../sgo-html5-app-desktop.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128

I googled this issue and found out that this error code is about authentication. But how could it sometimes work and sometimes not?

**EDIT:** 
Not sure if it's related but after 5 failed deployments, we restarted Jenkins and the ensuing deploy succeeded.

Comment: Sounds very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721629/jenkins-returned-status-code-128-with-github

Comment: Well, it sounds similar but from what I understand, the issue you linked is systematic. In my case, it sometimes succeed, without changing anything. Simply retrigerring a failed build could make it succeed the next time...

Comment: Makes sense, I agree with you. Then it's likely an issue with your Jenkins configuration; are the keys being regenerated dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure since I did not create/configure this setup but a colleague thinks the answer is no.

Comment: I see, hmm. Not sure.

Comment: Hi. Checking in to see if you had any success in the last 18 months. I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: We dumped Jenkins and Gerrit and everything is fine now. Not the answer you expected, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but we changed our workflow (no more Gerrit and Jenkins), hence making the whole issue disappear.