# Jenkins Blue Ocean fails on GitHub 'git checkout -b branch-name' with status code 128:

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-blueocean

following a YT tutorial [Getting Started with Blue Ocean's Visual Pipeline Editor](https://youtu.be/5Nct-jrZBbM?t=435), I struggle to proceed further after the second round of modification my Jenkinsfile using the BO Visual Editor.

When I hit the 'Save & run' button, Jenkins BO pipeline starts running, but fails with this:

```
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result  

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -b blue-ocean-editor 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40" returned status code 128:

stdout: 

stderr: fatal: A branch named 'blue-ocean-editor' already exists
```

If you look into my repo and [the particular commit(s)](https://github.com/delphym/HelloWorldProject/commit/af40ab6a99f1e94a45c57922380366967d7d6fb4) Jenkins had been able to create the 'blue-ocean-editor' branch in my initial commit (caused by the new BO pipeline) and also push the next commit "Expand my Blue Ocean pipeline", so I doubt that my Jenkins won't have the right credentials as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721629/jenkins-returned-status-code-128-with-github).

However there are some timeouts. Not sure how much is this of concern.
Anyway, here's the full output of my BO pipeline:

```
Branch indexing

Connecting to https://api.github.com using zxxxy/****** (GitHub Access Token)

Obtained Jenkinsfile from 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY

[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline

[Pipeline] node

Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HelloWorldProject/branches/blue-ocean-editor/workspace

[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] stage

[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)

[Pipeline] checkout

using credential github

 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/delphym/HelloWorldProject.git # timeout=10

Cleaning workspace

 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10

Resetting working tree

 > git reset --hard # timeout=10

 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10

Fetching without tags

Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/delphym/HelloWorldProject.git

 > git --version # timeout=10

using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHub Access Token

 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/delphym/HelloWorldProject.git +refs/heads/blue-ocean-editor:refs/remotes/origin/blue-ocean-editor # timeout=10

Checking out Revision 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40 (blue-ocean-editor)

 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10

 > git checkout -f 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40 # timeout=10

 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10

 > git checkout -b blue-ocean-editor 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40 # timeout=10

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // node

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...

[BFA] No failure causes found

[BFA] Done. 0s



GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result



hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -b blue-ocean-editor 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40" returned status code 128:

stdout: 

stderr: fatal: A branch named 'blue-ocean-editor' already exists.



    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2318)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$900(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2627)

Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout blue-ocean-editor with start point 9c164f507fa831c33d44d83e1f458ec50b433f40

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2649)

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1228)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Finished: FAILURE
```

I wonder what I could be doing wrong. I believe I have pretty much up-to-date Jenkins and all the plugins and OS, but briefly:
OS: Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.6 LTS
Jenkins: Jenkins ver. 2.161 (a bit behind, but I want to switch to the stable releases)
Plugins: [Blue Ocean](https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean) 1.13.2