# Azure App Service deploy of Spring Boot app not working from Jenkins

Tags: java, azure, jenkins, azure-web-app-service

I have a Spring Boot application running as an Azure App Service. I can deploy it using the Maven plugin, but not from Jenkins. The strange thing is that it has already worked from Jenkins before.

When deploying with Maven (using `mvn azure-webapp:deploy`), I see something like:

```
[INFO] Auth Type : AZURE_CLI, Auth Files : [/Users/wdb/.azure/azureProfile.json, /Users/wdb/.azure/accessTokens.json]
[INFO] [Correlation ID: ab463b1c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx] Instance discovery was successful
[INFO] Subscription : MY_SUBSCRIPTION(797bdef0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)
[INFO] Updating App Service Plan...
[INFO] Updating target Web App...
[INFO] Successfully updated Web App.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to /Users/wdb/Projects/my-project/target/azure-webapp/my-project-backend-staging-80a97da7-6abf-49f4-9f4f-df92b8d38e20
[INFO] Trying to deploy artifact to my-project-backend-staging...
[INFO] Renaming /Users/wdb/Projects/my-project/target/azure-webapp/my-project-backend-staging-80a97da7-6abf-49f4-9f4f-df92b8d38e20/my-project-backend-staging-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to app.jar
[INFO] Deploying the zip package my-project-backend-staging-80a97da7-6abf-49f4-9f4f-df92b8d38e204401718728513612670.zip...
[INFO] Successfully deployed the artifact to https://my-project-backend-staging.azurewebsites.net
```

I have this in my `Jenkinsfile` (using the [Azure App Service Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-app-service/)):

```
                dir('target') {
                    sh '''
                        cp my-project-backend-*.jar app.jar
                        '''

                    azureWebAppPublish azureCredentialsId: 'JenkinsMyProjectBackendServicePrincipal',
                            resourceGroup: 'MYPROJECT-BACKEND',
                            appName: 'myproject-backend',
                            filePath: "app.jar"
                }
```

When the build is run, I see this in the logging:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://myproject-backend-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/myproject-backend-staging.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 74, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (1/48)           
remote: Compressing objects:   4% (2/48)           
remote: Compressing objects:   6% (3/48)           
remote: Compressing objects:   8% (4/48)           
remote: Compressing objects:  10% (5/48)           
remote: .

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:573)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:802)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:375)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721629/jenkins-returned-status-code-128-with-github) might help.

Comment: @AndrewS If it was a permissions problem, I don't understand how the 'Counting objects' could have been printed in the log?

Comment: @AndrewS  Andrew‘s comment should be useful to you. If your problem is solved, it is recommended to send out your answer. As for your doubts, I think this is the printing log record operation status of the system operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Azure Jenkins plugin checks the `linuxFxVersion` to contain `jre`. But if you use Java 11, this is not the case (The value is something like `JAVA|11-java11`). Because of that, it wrongly thinks that it is *not* a Java platform to deploy to.

I fixed the issue and opened a PR at https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-app-service-plugin/pull/63.

I am currently using my locally build version until they pick up this PR.

Next to that, I also had to create a zip file to make it fully work:

```
dir('target') {
    sh '''
        cp my-project-backend-*.jar app.jar
        '''
    zip zipFile: 'app.zip', glob: 'app.jar'

    azureWebAppPublish azureCredentialsId: 'JenkinsMyProjectBackendServicePrincipal',
            resourceGroup: 'MYPROJECT-BACKEND',
            appName: 'my-project-backend-staging',
            filePath: "app.zip"
}
```